# Optimizations in copying a range

Tags: c++, optimization

While reading sources of GNU C++ standard library, I found some code for copying (or moving, if possible) a range of iterators (file `stl_algobase.h`), which uses template specialization for some optimizations. A comment corresponding to it says:

> All of these auxiliary structs serve two purposes.  (1) Replace calls to copy with memmove whenever possible.  (Memmove, not memcpy, because the input and output ranges are permitted to overlap.) (2) If we're using random access iterators, then write the loop as a for loop with an explicit count.

The specialization using the second optimization looks like this:

```
template<>
struct __copy_move<false, false, random_access_iterator_tag>
{
  template<typename _II, typename _OI>
    static _OI
    __copy_m(_II __first, _II __last, _OI __result)
    { 
  typedef typename iterator_traits<_II>::difference_type _Distance;
  for(_Distance __n = __last - __first; __n > 0; --__n)
    {
      *__result = *__first;
      ++__first;
      ++__result;
    }
  return __result;
  }
};
```

So, I have two questions concerning this

- How can `memmove` increase the spead of copying? Is it implemented somehow more effective than a simple loop?
- How can using explicit counter in the `for` loop affect the performance?

Some clarification: I would like to see some optimization examples actually used by compilers, not elaboration on the possibility of those.

**Edit**: the first question is quite nicely answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776085/why-is-memcpy-and-memmove-faster-than-pointer-increments).

Comment: The explicit counter may enable the compiler to perform some optimizations, such as loop unrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the second question, the explicit count does indeed lead to more opportunities for loop unrolling, though even with pointers iterating through a fixed size array, gcc does not perform aggressive unrolling unless asked to do so with `-funroll-loops`. The other gain comes from a potentially simpler end-of-loop comparison test for non-trivial iterators.

On a Core i7-4770, I benchmarked the time spent performing a copy of a maximally-aligned 2048-long integer array with a while loop and explicit count copy implementation. (Times in microseconds, includes call overhead; minimum of 200 samples of a timing loop with warm-up.)

```
                                            while      count

gcc -O3                                     0.179      0.178
gcc -O3 -march=native                       0.097      0.095
gcc -O3 -march=native -funroll-loops        0.066      0.066
```

In each case, the generated code is very similar; the `while` version does a bit more work at the end in each case, handling checks that there aren't any entries left to copy that didn't fill out a whole 128-bit (SSE) or 256-bit (AVX) register, but these are pretty much taken care of by the branch predictor. The `gcc -O3` assembly for each is as follows (leaving out assembler directives). `while` version:

```
array_copy_while(int (&) [2048], int (&) [2048]):
        leaq    8192(%rdi), %rax
        leaq    4(%rdi), %rdx
        movq    %rax, %rcx
        subq    %rdx, %rcx
        movq    %rcx, %rdx
        shrq    $2, %rdx
        leaq    1(%rdx), %r8
        cmpq    $8, %r8
        jbe     .L11
        leaq    16(%rsi), %rdx
        cmpq    %rdx, %rdi
        leaq    16(%rdi), %rdx
        setae   %cl
        cmpq    %rdx, %rsi
        setae   %dl
        orb     %dl, %cl
        je      .L11
        movq    %r8, %r9
        xorl    %edx, %edx
        xorl    %ecx, %ecx
        shrq    $2, %r9
        leaq    0(,%r9,4), %r10
.L9:
        movdqa  (%rdi,%rdx), %xmm0
        addq    $1, %rcx
        movdqa  %xmm0, (%rsi,%rdx)
        addq    $16, %rdx
        cmpq    %rcx, %r9
        ja      .L9
        leaq    0(,%r10,4), %rdx
        addq    %rdx, %rdi
        addq    %rdx, %rsi
        cmpq    %r10, %r8
        je      .L1
        movl    (%rdi), %edx
        movl    %edx, (%rsi)
        leaq    4(%rdi), %rdx
        cmpq    %rdx, %rax
        je      .L1
        movl    4(%rdi), %edx
        movl    %edx, 4(%rsi)
        leaq    8(%rdi), %rdx
        cmpq    %rdx, %rax
        je      .L20
        movl    8(%rdi), %eax
        movl    %eax, 8(%rsi)
        ret
.L11:
        movl    (%rdi), %edx
        addq    $4, %rdi
        addq    $4, %rsi
        movl    %edx, -4(%rsi)
        cmpq    %rdi, %rax
        jne     .L11
.L1:
        rep ret
.L20:
        rep ret
```

`count` version:

```
array_copy_count(int (&) [2048], int (&) [2048]):
        leaq    16(%rsi), %rax
        movl    $2048, %ecx
        cmpq    %rax, %rdi
        leaq    16(%rdi), %rax
        setae   %dl
        cmpq    %rax, %rsi
        setae   %al
        orb     %al, %dl
        je      .L23
        movw    $512, %cx
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        xorl    %edx, %edx
.L29:
        movdqa  (%rdi,%rax), %xmm0
        addq    $1, %rdx
        movdqa  %xmm0, (%rsi,%rax)
        addq    $16, %rax
        cmpq    %rdx, %rcx
        ja      .L29
        rep ret
.L23:
        xorl    %eax, %eax
.L31:
        movl    (%rdi,%rax,4), %edx
        movl    %edx, (%rsi,%rax,4)
        addq    $1, %rax
        cmpq    %rax, %rcx
        jne     .L31
        rep ret
```

When the iterators are more complicated however, the difference becomes more pronounced. Consider a hypothetical container that stores values in a series of fixed-sized allocated buffers. An iterator comprises a pointer to the chain of blocks, a block index and a block offset. Comparison of two iterators requires potentially two comparisons. Incrementing the iterator requires checking if we pop over a block boundary.

I made such a container, and performed the same benchmark for copying a 2000-long container of `int`, with a block size of 512 `int`s.

```
                                            while      count

gcc -O3                                     1.560      2.818
gcc -O3 -march=native                       1.660      2.854
gcc -O3 -march=native -funroll-loops        1.432      2.858
```

That looks weird! Oh wait, it's because gcc 4.8 has a misoptimisation, where it uses conditional moves instead of nice, branch-predictor friendly comparisons. ([gcc bug 56309](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56309)).

Let's try icc on a different machine (Xeon E5-2670).

```
                                            while      count

icc -O3                                     3.952      3.704
icc -O3 -xHost                              3.898      3.624
```

This is closer to what we'd expect, a small but significant improvement from the simpler loop condition. On a different architecture, the gain is more pronounced. clang targeting a PowerA2 at 1.6GHz:

```
                                            while      count

bgclang -O3                                36.528     31.623
```

I'll omit the assembly, as it's quite long!