# When __builtin_memcpy is replaced with libc's memcpy

Tags: gcc, c99, memcpy, built-in

There is a version of C99/posix `memcpy` function in GCC: `__builtin_memcpy`.

Sometimes it can be replaced by GCC to inline version of memcpy and in other cases it is replaced by call to libc's memcpy. E.g. it was noted [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/29183/):

> Finally, on a compiler note, __builtin_memcpy can fall back to emitting a memcpy function call.

What is the logic in this selection? Is it logic the same in other gcc-compatible compilers, like clang/llvm, intel c++ compiler, PCC, suncc (oracle studio)?

When I should prefer of using __builtin_memcpy over plain memcpy?

Comment: It appears that it uses an inline version when the size is a compile time constant and it's less than or equal to 8192.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had been experimenting with the builtin replacement some time ago and I found out that the `<string.h>` functions are only replaced when the size of the source argument can be known at compile time.  In which case the call to `libc` is replaced directly by unrolled code.

Unless you compile with `-fno-builtin`, `-ansi`, `-std=c89` or something similar, it actually doesn't matter wether you use the `__builtin_` prefix or not.

Although it's hard to follow, the code that deciedes whether to emit a library call or a chunk of code seems to be [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/expr.c;h=7e909bc0f5c8035cfe17f643cbad826c2d41cd6c;hb=9bcca88e24e64d4e23636aafa3404088b13bcb0e#l1102).

Comment: Which gcc version and optimisation level was studied?

Comment: `gcc` version 4.6 using `-O3` and `-fomit-frame-pointer`.  Before answering I tested with 4.7 as well.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  The functions are replaced from the first optimization level (`-O1` or simply `-O`).