# avoiding a libc function call when copying chars by using std::copy instead of std::memcpy?

Tags: c++, gcc

I hope this isn't a duplicate, since similar questions have been asked. I am concerned about the use of `std::memcpy` when gcc decides to use the [libc's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747891/when-builtin-memcpy-is-replaced-with-libcs-memcpy). This probably does not happen, if we use `std::copy` instead, that is, we avoid this function call into libc? And if so, how does the generated code compare to the libc's implementation of `std::memcpy`?

Comment: I wonder wheterh this should be closed as too broad. It doesn't mention input or output ranges, element type, etcetera.

Comment: I do mention element type, ranges are arbitrary.

Comment: `std::copy` works on the principle of `type system` and `std::memcpy` purely works on bytes. It will be tedious and not so clean to use `std::memcpy` inside `std::copy` after evaluating/examining the parameters of `std::copy`.

Comment: @sameerkn I know all that, but it needs to support chars also, just like memcpy. I am asking about avoiding the function call into libc and if the generated code is crappy or good.

Comment: If you see the possible implementation (std::copy)[http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy] then you will find that its better to avoid `memcpy` altogether, since elements are assigned/copied using `operator=`.

Comment: @sameerkn: it may be tedious and not so clean, but providers of standard algorithms do it anyway, because it's fast.

Comment: @sameerkn I need to copy bytes fast and the call into libc was a sore in my eye, that's why I asked the question.

Comment: @user1095108: the reason gcc calls into libc is that it thinks it's faster. If the real question is "what's faster" then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707012

Comment: @SteveJessop I just wanted to avoid the branch without writing my own `memcpy()`, which, I suppose, is commendable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite a dupe question, but here is [an example of g++ calling `memmove` or `memcpy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4707028/13005) as part of the implementation of `std::copy`.

In short no, using `std::copy` *does not* in general prevent GCC from using libc.

If you really want to block the optimization then there might be some combination of compiler options that does it, I don't know. You'd have to look into exactly how `std::copy` is implemented, they might just happen to have written it in a way that it can't be disabled.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter, or help depending on your perspective.

`std::copy` is, in at least one standard library implementation I know of, implemented in such a way that it detects if its inputs are contiguous iterators over trivially copyable types, and will just use `std::memmove` in that case anyway. And the compiler may even recognize that the ranges passed are distinct and will replace that with a `memcpy` in turn.

In other words, you can switch to `std::copy`, but chances are the compiler will just switch it back.

Answer (score 1):

`std::memcpy` is typically a `std` namespace wrapper around the C `memcpy`.

Since most modern C libraries provide highly optimised implementations of this function, including `restrict` pointer arguments - a keyword not available in C++11/14 - it's probably more efficient. If the compiler can prove `std::copy` operates on distinct ranges, it might also use something like a `__builtin_memcpy` for gcc. The elements would probably still be required to satisfy the `is_trivially_copyable` type trait, for example.

The exception may be if you are using `std::copy` on very short ranges, and the compiler can't deduce the range length at compile time, but still generates a `mem[cpy|move]` call. I would still be sceptical that any call overhead to a `memcpy` implementation would be significant. You'd need to look at profiling.

Comment: It's just disturbing to me, I'd prefer and inlined memcpy, but gcc emits a call into libc, still no worries, I can copy&paste a good implementation in there, there are many good ones out there. `std::copy` is much more than a simple wrapper, according to my experience and of some other people, often it is more efficient.

Comment: @user1095108 - if you look at the implementations for `memcpy` in say [`glibc`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch;h=a580c13d7c24f8060128526603c386f7410ea695;hb=fdfc9260b61d3d72541f18104d24c7bcb0ce5ca2) (assuming you're using x86-64, though there are other architectures), you can see that there are highly optimised assembly implementations, with variants for SSE/AVX, etc., covering `memcpy`, `memmove`, etc. I still don't really understand *why* this bothers you so much. If you provided an example where this a problem, the answers would be less vague.