# location of memcpy arm

Tags: arm, memcpy

I'm using memcpy on my ARM platform and I want to view the sourecode of memcpy. Viewing an objectdump from my sourcecode, I know this memcpy is used:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/libc.a(lib_a-memcpy.o)
```

How can I look at the .c source code of memcpy?

Comment: look at the sourcecode for libc if you are using libc or newlib if newlib, or if it is from gcclib then from gcc, etc..  dont be surprised if you find it is written in assembly.

Comment: you can also just disassemble it.

Comment: I am using arm gcc compile. Is there a sourcecode for libc for arm gcc, or is there only one sourcecode for libc working on multiple platforms?

Comment: there is a c library that comes with the gcc sources, but that is not the only c library in the world and certainly not the only memcpy.

Answer (score 0):

On *some* compilers (with *some* optimization flags), `memcpy` would use some `__builtin_memcpy` which is magically handled by the compiler (and could even not emit any function call, but always be inlined and specialized).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11747891/841108) related question and the [documentation of GCC builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html). Ultimately, dive into the source code of your GCC compiler.

Look also into the source code of your `libc`. It probably mentions `__builtin_mempcy` in some internal header.

Of course, use `gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O` and see the generated assembler file `*.s`