# Mergesort pThread implementation taking same time as single-threaded

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads-win32

(I have tried to simplify this as much as i could to find out where I'm doing something wrong.)

The ideea of the code is that I have a global array *v (I hope using this array isn't slowing things down, the threads should never acces the same value because they all work on different ranges) and I try to create 2 threads each one sorting the first half, respectively the second half by calling the function merge_sort() with the respective parameters.

On the threaded run, i see the process going to 80-100% cpu usage (on dual core cpu) while on the no threads run it only stays at 50% yet the run times are very close.

---

**This is the (relevant) code:**

//These are the 2 sorting functions, each thread will call merge_sort(..). Is this a problem? both threads calling same (normal) function?

```
void merge (int *v, int start, int middle, int end) {
    //dynamically creates 2 new arrays for the v[start..middle] and v[middle+1..end]
    //copies the original values into the 2 halves
    //then sorts them back into the v array
}

void merge_sort (int *v, int start, int end) {
    //recursively calls merge_sort(start, (start+end)/2) and merge_sort((start+end)/2+1, end) to sort them
    //calls merge(start, middle, end) 
}
```

//here i'm expecting each thread to be created and to call merge_sort on its specific range (this is a simplified version of the original code to find the bug easier)

```
void* mergesort_t2(void * arg) {
    t_data* th_info = (t_data*)arg;
    merge_sort(v, th_info->a, th_info->b);
    return (void*)0;
}
```

//in main I simply create 2 threads calling the above function

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //some stuff

    //getting the clock to calculate run time
    clock_t t_inceput, t_sfarsit;
    t_inceput = clock();

    //ignore crt_depth for this example (in the full code i'm recursively creating new threads and i need this to know when to stop)
    //the a and b are the range of values the created thread will have to sort
    pthread_t thread[2];
    t_data next_info[2];
    next_info[0].crt_depth = 1;
    next_info[0].a = 0;
    next_info[0].b = n/2;
    next_info[1].crt_depth = 1;
    next_info[1].a = n/2+1;
    next_info[1].b = n-1;

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        if (pthread_create (&thread[i], NULL, &mergesort_t2, &next_info[i]) != 0) {
            cerr<<"error\n;";
            return err;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        if (pthread_join(thread[i], &status) != 0) {
            cerr<<"error\n;";
            return err;
        }
    }

    //now i merge the 2 sorted halves
    merge(v, 0, n/2, n-1);

    //calculate end time
    t_sfarsit = clock();

    cout<<"Sort time (s): "<<double(t_sfarsit - t_inceput)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<endl;
    delete [] v;
}
```

---

Output (on 1 million values):

```
Sort time (s): 1.294
```

Output with direct calling of merge_sort, no threads:

```
Sort time (s): 1.388
```

---

Output (on 10 million values):

```
Sort time (s): 12.75
```

Output with direct calling of merge_sort, no threads:

```
Sort time (s): 13.838
```

---

**Solution:**

I'd like to thank WhozCraig and Adam too as they've hinted to this from the beginning.

I've used the `inplace_merge(..)` function instead of my own and the program run times are as they should now.

Here's my initial merge function (not really sure if the initial, i've probably modified it a few times since, also array indices might be wrong right now, i went back and forth between [a,b] and [a,b), this was just the last commented-out version):

```
void merge (int *v, int a, int m, int c) { //sorts v[a,m] - v[m+1,c] in v[a,c]

    //create the 2 new arrays
    int *st = new int[m-a+1];
    int *dr = new int[c-m+1];
    //copy the values
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 <= m-a; i1++)
        st[i1] = v[a+i1];
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 <= c-(m+1); i2++)
        dr[i2] = v[m+1+i2];

    //merge them back together in sorted order
    int is=0, id=0;
    for (int i=0; i<=c-a; i++)  {
        if (id+m+1 > c || (a+is <= m && st[is] <= dr[id])) {
            v[a+i] = st[is];
            is++;
        }
        else {
            v[a+i] = dr[id];
            id++;
        }
    }
    delete st, dr;
}
```

all this was replaced with:

```
inplace_merge(v+a, v+m, v+c);
```

---

Edit, some times on my 3ghz dual core cpu:

1 million values:
1 thread : 7.236 s
2 threads: 4.622 s
4 threads: 4.692 s

10 million values:
1 thread : 82.034 s
2 threads: 46.189 s
4 threads: 47.36  s

Comment: your `merge` is still sequential. What proportion of time is spent in the `merge_sort` and `merge` stages?

Comment: Also just to make sure you're to re-inventing the wheel:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/merge/

Comment: You're not really saving much, and paying for what you do save with thread management. Further, your merge could be considerably simpler (and in fact using [`std::inplace_merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge) would dramatically simplify this). And why are you even launching two threads at all? You can easily launch *one*, then use the *current* thread as the "other".

Comment: @Adam the final merge call takes 0.171 seconds, I don't think there's an easy way to check how much time it stays in those functions.
I know the merge is sequential but I'm thinking that using 2 cores instead of just one should speed up a lot.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have implemented this program using MPI too and I'm trying to keep the same structure to make a comparison between them. The full version of the program can use different numbers of threads.

The basic ideea is this:
IF not reached N threads: |
I create new thread to sort left half of current range |
I create new thread to sort right half of current range |
Wait for both of them to finish |
Merge the results .

Now, if i want 4 threads, they will be created recursively from those 2 create new thread commands

Comment: I used these exact merge(..) and merge_sort(..) functions on the MPI implementation and they sped up the runtime by almost 2x so I don't think those are the problem, I think there's something specific to pThreads I'm doing wrong because I don't have a lot of experience with them.

Comment: @dany123 I understand how the division of work is laid out. My point was dedicating the *current* thread to doing nothing but *waiting* after launching two other threads is a waste. Rather than launch+launch+wait you could just as easily launch+work+wait and reduce the startup penalties by 50%. That was my point.

Comment: This was what I was referring to: [See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbf70209e5f44b69). Dunno if it helps, but best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry, I understand now what you mean, I was hoping creating a thread that just waits isn't a big deal as (i think) it makes the code more readable.  I did try to create 2nd thread for 2nd half, sort 1st half in current thread, wait for 2nd thread to end but sadly I get the exact same time.

Comment: One possible problem is that [copying data using "for" loops is something _really_ slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729046/memcpy-vs-for-loop-whats-the-proper-way-to-copy-an-array-from-a-pointer). You may try using either [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) or [`std::copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/)

Comment: @BrunoFerreira you're right, it was probably the sum of all the extra operations my code does compared to the <algorithm> one, good thing to remember for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one thing that struck me: "dynamically creates 2 new arrays[...]". Since both threads will need memory from the system, they need to acquire a lock for that, which could well be your bottleneck. In particular the idea of doing microscopic array allocations sounds horribly inefficient. Someone suggested an in-place sort that doesn't need any additional storage, which is much better for performance.

Another thing is the often-forgotten starting half-sentence for any big-O complexity measurements: "There is an n0 so that for all n>n0...". In other words, maybe you haven't reached n0 yet? I recently saw a video (hopefully someone else will remember it) where some people tried to determine this limit for some algorithms, and their results were that these limits are **surprisingly high**.

Comment: I was just about to post this, I've modified my program to use inplace_merge instead of my merge implementation and now the numbers look as they should.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: since OP uses Windows, my answer below (which incorrectly assumed Linux) might not apply. I left it for sake of those who might find the information useful.

---

`clock()` is a wrong interface for measuring time on Linux: it measures CPU time used by the program (see http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock), which in case of multiple threads is the sum of CPU time for all threads. You need to measure elapsed, or wallclock, time. See more details in this SO question: [C: using clock() to measure time in multi-threaded programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962785/c-using-clock-to-measure-time-in-multi-threaded-programs), which also tells what API can be used instead of `clock()`.

In the MPI-based implementation that you try to compare with, two different processes are used (that's how MPI typically enables concurrency), and the CPU time of the second process is not included - so the CPU time is close to wallclock time. Nevertheless, it's still wrong to use CPU time (and so `clock()`) for performance measurement, even in serial programs; for one reason, if a program waits for e.g. a network event or a message from another MPI process, it still spends time - but not CPU time.

*Update*: In Microsoft's implementation of C run-time library, [`clock()` returns wall-clock time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e2ess30.aspx), so is OK to use for your purpose. It's unclear though if you use Microsoft's toolchain or something else, like Cygwin or MinGW.

Comment: Timing it with timeGetTime() instead gives the same number. Also I did try to time it myself and it doesn't look like this is the problem, I think my code somehow doesn't run the threads concurently.

Comment: Oh, you run on Windows? I got misled by the use of pthreads and assumed Linux.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not mentioning that.