# How can I copy the first i amount of characters in a character array into another character array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, copy

```
read(client_sockfd, &chID, 4);
char newID[4];
for(int i; i<5; i++){
     newID[i] = chID[i];
}
```

I'm reading char chID[4] over a socket. I want to put the first 4 characters into newID. Above is what I've tried, but I get some weird output when I copy newID into a string and print it out. Any guidance?

Comment: You don't have `i=0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `i` within the `for` loop without initialising it.  This is the reason you get 'weird values'.  In order to rectify, you need to write:

`for(int i=0; i<5; i++)`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a difference or any benefit to either this method or memcpy? Or are they doing the same thing?

Comment: @anscmc You are good to use both.  I posted the above answer in response to the specific code you are using and to point out why you are getting *weird values*.  Which approach would be better depends on what exactly you are trying to accomplish.  Additional details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729046/memcpy-vs-for-loop-whats-the-proper-way-to-copy-an-array-from-a-pointer).

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the bytes:

```
memcpy(newID, chID, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more note that it seems some people have overlooked here: if chId is length 4 then the loop bounds are i=0;i<4.  That way you get i=0,1,2,3.  (General programming tip, unroll loops in your head when possible.  At least until you are satisfied that the program really is doing what you meant it to.)

NB: You're not copying chId into a string.  You're copying it into a char array.  That may seem like semantics, but "string" names a data type in C++ which is distinct from an array of characters.  Got it right in the title, wrong in the question description.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. About the string convert: I didn't post that code; sorry that wasn't clear. After this loop I was using "string str(newID)" to copy newID into str, then printing it out with cout. I think with the three answer I've received, I've found my solution. Thank you!