# How can I copy a part of an array to another array in C++?

Tags: c++

This is the same question asked in C# but i need for C++

How can I copy a part of an array to another array?

Consider I'm having

```
    int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Now if I give the start index and end index of the array a it should get copied to another array.

Like if I give start index as 1 and end index as 3, the elements 2, 3, 4 should get copied in the new array.

In C# it is done as following

```
     int[] b = new int[3];
    Array.Copy(a, 1, b, 0, 3);
```

Is there any simple way like this to do the same task in C++?

Comment: Even better, use `std::vector` instead of the arrays in the first place. It has a constructor that does what you're doing, among many other great features.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, use [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
std::copy(a + src_begin_index,
          a + src_begin_index + elements_to_copy,
          b + dest_begin_index);
```

The equivalent of your C# example would be:

```
std::copy(a + 1, a + 4, b);
```

Comment: Just make sure you don't overflow the bounds of your destination!

Comment: I'd go for `copy_n`... `std::copy_n( a+src_begin_index, elements_to_copy, b+dst_begin_index )`

Comment: A great answer indeed. To suplement this, `memcopy` isn't even faster than `copy`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707012/is-it-better-to-use-stdmemcpy-or-stdcopy-in-terms-to-performance

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want a dynamically-allocated array as in the C# example, the simplest way is:

```
std::vector<int> b(a.begin() + 1, a.begin() + 4);
```

This also has the advantage that it will automatically release the allocated memory when it's destroyed; if you use `new` yourself, then you'll also need to use `delete` to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

For simple C-style arrays you can use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(b, &a[1], sizeof(int) * 3);
```

This line copies `sizeof(int) * 3` bytes (i.e. 12 bytes) from index 1 of `a`, with `b` as a destination.

Answer (score 1):

There is the `C` [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/) command, which you can use like this:

```
memcpy(destinationArray, sourceArray, sizeof(*destinationArray) * elementsToCopy);
```

There is also [`std::copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/), which is a more `C++` way of doing it:

```
std::copy(source, source + elementsInSource, destination);
```

Note that neither of these functions check to make sure that enough memory has been allocated, so use at your own risk!

Comment: The use of `std:copy` is incorrect, as the the second argument should be one-past-the-end (`source+elementsInSource`), without the -1

Comment: @DaveS ok, thanks. I haven't used C++ in a while, so thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using st standard library algorithm `copy`:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  int array[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 }; // note: no int[] array
  int *b = new int[3];
  std::copy(array+1, array+4, b); 
  // copies elements 1 (inclusive) to 4 (exclusive), ie. values 2,3,4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vector in CPP, you can do it this way -

Suppose you want to copy elements from **arr** from index **A** to index **B**, you can do it this way -

```
vector<int>nums(arr.begin()+A, arr.begin()+B+1);
```

**Note - nums will be created as A[start, end) so we need to add extra 1**