# C++ equivalent of Python's : for array indexing

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, slice

When working with arrays in C++, is there a simple way to access multiple indices of an array at once à la Python's `:`?

E.g. I have an array x of length 100. If I wanted the first 50 values of this array in Python I could write `x[0:50]`. In C++ is there an easier way to access this same portion of the array other than `x[0,1,2,...,49]`?

Comment: Depends on what you do with that slice. I'd lean towards a pair of pointers.

Comment: other than x[0,1,2,...,49] ? i guess you meant `x[0], x[1], x[2]...` for single elements. The way to access a portion of an array is via iterators

Comment: if array elements are primitive type, `std::memcpy` will be a good choice.

Comment: @Quentin I want to assign/update that portion of the array.

Comment: It kinda also depends on whether you are talking about raw C-style arrays, or `std::array`.  (And `std::vector` is another class to consider).  I would *recommend* using those classes, and the answers here might be helpful.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102029/how-can-i-copy-a-part-of-an-array-to-another-array-in-c  If you wanted to *modify* the elements in question in the original array, you could consider making it an array of int references or pointers.  Or just have the function doing the modifying take `begin` and `end` parameters.

Comment: Boost provides an "iterator range" pseudo-container.  e.g. `for (auto& elt : boost::make_iterator_range(x.begin(), x.begin() + 50)) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can come is probably using iterators. In `<algorithm>` you can find a bunch of functions that act on an iterator range, for example:

```
#include <algorithm>

int x[100];
int new_value = 1;
std::fill(std::begin(x), std::begin(x) + 50, new_value);
```

This would change the values in the range to `new_value`. Other functions in `<algorithm>` can copy a range (`std::copy`), apply a function to elements in a range (`std::transform`), etc.

If you are using this, be aware that `std::begin` and `std::end` only work with arrays, not with pointers! Safer and easier would be to use containers like `std::vector`.

Comment: The question says you need to retrieve first 50 values sort of thing

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like below

```
int main()
{
  int myints[]={10,20,30,40,50,60,70};
  array<int,5> mysubints;

  std::copy(myints, myints+5, mysubints.begin());

  for (auto it = mysubints.begin(); it!=mysubints.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << ' ' << *it;

  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

you can also use vector instead of array data type