# copying a buffer in a struct in C++ style

Tags: c++, struct, styles, copy

Say i have a struct like

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char flag, type;
    unsigned short id;
    uint32 size;
} THdr;
```

and a buffer of data coming from a UDP comunication, i have a buffer of bytes and its size (`data` and `data_size`). data size is bigger than `sizeof(THdr)`.

The struct is at the beginning of the buffer, and i want to copy it to a struct defined in the code, `THdr Struct_copy` .

I know that i can use `memcpy(&Struct_copy,data[0],sizeof(Struct_copy));` but i would like to use a "C++ style" way, like using `std::copy`.

any clue?

Comment: If you have a working single-line implementation, why complicate it (and quite possibly slow down) because you want something more 'stylish'? `memcpy` is a fine solution for this, that's what it's for.

Comment: Use `std::memcpy` instead :-) `std::` makes it more C++ish!

Comment: because depending on the compiler memcpy can be slower than std::copy, at least is what they said in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707012/c-memcpy-vs-stdcopy

Comment: That `uint32` -- if coming over the network, it should have a different byte ordering.

Comment: `memcpy` is not correct here either, and in general you can't do stuff like that portably (not saying it won't work in all cases you care for). For example, in general the compiler can inject padding between struct members to ensure proper alignment. In order to get safe offsets, you would have to enable packing in the structure which is not possible portably. `char` and `short` may not have the sizes you desire. `uint32` may not even be available on the platform. All of them can have wrong endianness… Yes, C++ is fun! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
THdr hdr;
std::copy(&hdr, &hdr + 1, reinterpret_cast<THdr*>(data));
```

Should copy one `THdr` structure from `data` to `hdr`.

It can also be much simpler:

```
THdr hdr;
hdr = *reinterpret_cast<THdr*>(data);
```

This last works in C as well:

```
THdr hdr;
hdr = *(THdr *) data;
```

---

Or why not create a constructor that takes the data as input? Like

```
struct THdr
{
    explicit THdr(const unsigned char* data)
        {
            THdr* other = reinterpret_cast<THdr*>(data);
            *this = *other;
        }

    // ...
};
```

Then it can be used such as

```
THdr hdr(data);
```

Comment: Doesn't `reinterpret_cast` have run-time efficiency penalty?

Comment: @MM. Nope, it just tells the compiler to treat one type as another type, i.e. it should "reinterpret" the type.

Comment: Maybe that "reinterpret" imposes cost... Does it cost compile-time or run-time? I'm a litte confused!

Comment: @MM. Definitely no runtime-cost, barely even compile-time cost. Whatever "cost" it has on the compilation, it will be negligible and not even measurable. It's actually only a nicer way of the old C-style cast.

Comment: tryed, but the compiler says [bcc32 Error] def.h(104): E2031 Cannot cast from 'const unsigned char *' to 'THdr *'

Comment: maybe it should not be const unsigned char* but only unsigned char*

Comment: No "Should copy one THdr structure from data to hdr":

from hdr to data

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is wrong here. You mustn't dereference a `reinterpret_cast` pointer unless you `reinterpret_cast` it back to the original type, see [When to use reinterpret_cast?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573294/when-to-use-reinterpret-cast). You want to use double `static_cast` instead (to `void*`, then to target type).

Answer (score 2):

There is no "clever" way to do this in C++. If it doesn't involve `memcpy`, then you need `std::copy` and you will have to use casts to `const unsigned char *` to make the datatype of the source and/or destination match up.

There are various other ways to "copy some data", such as type-punning, but again, it's not a "better" solution than `memcpy` - just different.

C++ was designed to accept C-code, so if there's nothing wrong with your current code, then I don't see why you should change it.