# Which parts of the C standard library are not covered by (the rest of) the C++ standard library?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

> [The C++ library includes the same definitions as the C language library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/)

But the C++ library seems to duplicate (/extend) some of the functionality of the C library in non-C-library headers. For example, the C library has <string.h>, and the C++ library has both <cstring> and <string>; the C library has <time.h>, and the C+ library has both <ctime> and <chrono>.

If I need a string class, I assume that I am better off using <string> instead of <cstring>, because <string> can benefit from all the non-C functionality in C++ (e.g. exceptions). But there is functionality in the C library that doesn't exist in any other form in the C++ library. For example, I couldn't find anything like memcpy and memcmp outside <cstring>.

Which parts of the C library have no analogue in the non-C-library headers?

(If the version of the C++ standard matters for this, I am interested in C++11.)

Comment: note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707012/c-memcpy-vs-stdcopy

Comment: The reason there's nothing like memcpy and memcmp in `<string>` is that `<string>` isn't a re-implementation of `<cstring>`, it's an entirely separate approach to the abstract problem space "text manipulation". One that happens to differ significantly from the approach taken by `<cstring>`, partly because it used a different language and partly for language-agnostic reasons (e.g. nul termination vs. length).

Comment: `memcpy`=> `std::copy`, `memcmp` => `std::equal`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There aren't that many headers, so lets just list them. Some could be replaced by language facilities, rather than libraries. (I haven't enumerated every function in each header, so I might have missed the odd function that doesn't have a C++ alternative when most of its colleagues do.)

```
C library         C++ alternatives
assert.h          Exceptions
complex.h         <complex>
ctype.h           None (or maybe <locale>, if you want to jump down that rabbit-hole)
errno.h           None (but only applies to C functions)
fenv.h            None
float.h           <limits>
inttypes.h        (See breakdown)
   formatting     <iostream>
   strto...       <string> (C++11), <sstream>
   imaxabs        std::abs overloads
   imaxdiv        std::div overloads
iso646.h          Language
locale.h          <locale>
math.h            None (extended with C++ overloads)
setjmp.h          Exceptions
signal.h          None
stdarg.h          Variadic templates (C++11)
stdbool.h         Language
stddef.h          None
stdint.h          None
stdio.h           <iostream> etc.
stdlib.h          (See breakdown)
   atof etc.      <sstream>, <string> (C++11)
   rand etc.      <random> (C++11)
   malloc etc.    new, containers
   abort etc.     None
   bsearch etc.   <algorithm>
   abs etc.       None (extended with C++ overloads)
   mb strings     None
string.h          <string>, <algorithm>
tgmath.h          <cmath> (C++ overloads)
time.h            <chrono> (C++11)
wchar.h           <iostream> etc.
wctype.h          None
```

To summarise:

> Which parts of the C library have no analogue in the non-C-library headers?

`[w]ctype.h`, `errno.h`, `fenv.h`, `fenv.h`, `math.h`, `signal.h`, `stddef.h`, `stdint.h`, some of `stdlib.h`. Before C++11, also `stdarg.h`, `time.h` and more of `stdlib.h`

Comment: The features from `ctype.h` are covered by the facet `std::ctype` in `<locale>`.

Comment: The features in `stdint.h` are covered by `<cstdint>`

Comment: @Morwenn: OK, I have little knowledge of <locale>.

Comment: @timwoj: Yes, that's the C++ wrapper for the C library header, just as for example <csdtdef> is the wrapper for <stddef.h>

Comment: @MikeSeymour No wonder. I think that it is one of the less "documented" parts of the standard. There are very few articles on the internet about `<locale>` compared to the rest of the standard :)