# Why can I not copy a C-style array to std::array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, stl, stdarray

I have this code:

```
 std::array<int,16> copyarray(int input[16])
{
    std::array<int, 16> result;
    std::copy(std::begin(input), std::end(input), std::begin(result));
    return result;
}
```

When I try to compile this code, I am getting this error:

```
'std::begin': no matching overloaded function found
```

and a similar error for `std::end`.

What is the problem and how I can fix it?

Comment: Size of array parameter does not work this way, it is equal to `int *input`

Comment: @Slava How to fix it?

Comment: Simply don't use C style arrays. They don't know their size and get converted to pointers when used as function parameters. No `std::begin` overload accepts pointer type.

Comment: @Ron Avoiding arrays might be the intention of the question - possibly there is an array somewhere in code mans cannot change?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26219764/2785528

Comment: Possible duplicate -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/26219721/2785528

Comment: You can also copy between them with `std::memcpy( result.data(), input, sizeof(input) );` It might be a good habit to define both array sizes as the same `constexpr size_t` value. If you retype `16` in multiple places, and they get out of sync, you would have a buffer overflow or underflow.

Answer (score 41):

In parameter declaration, `int input[16]` is same as `int* input`. And when you pass argument array would [decay to pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay), both mean the information about size of the array is lost. And [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) can't work with pointers.

You could change it to pass-by-reference, which reserve the array's size.

```
std::array<int,16> copyarray(int (&input)[16])
```

Note that you can only pass array with exact size of `16` to the function now.

Comment: ...or use raw pointers (`input` and `input+16`) for the algorithm. Of course not recommended, but sometimes one has no other choice

Comment: You can even add missing `const`.

Answer (score 34):

Everything important [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50489769/1312382) already, you can get the function just a little bit more flexible:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
std::array<T, N> copyarray(T const (&input)[N])
{
    std::array<T, N> result;
    std::copy(std::begin(input), std::end(input), std::begin(result));
    return result;
}
```

(Late) edit: There *is* a disadvantage with the approach above: You'll need to copy the returned array on assignment, as it doesn't contain any truely movable data (that's the same for raw arrays already). You can avoid this drawback by directly copying into the target array:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void copyarray(std::array<T, N>& target, T const (&source)[N])
{
    std::copy(std::begin(source), std::end(source), std::begin(target));
}
```

This mimicks the assignment `target = source`; if you like better, you can swap the parameters, of course, to have the output parameter last.

Usage (as is):

```
int source[7] = { };
std::array<int, sizeof(source)/sizeof(*source)> target;
copyarray(target, source);
```

Comment: template <typename T, size_t N> it is from <array> to `std::array` definition

Comment: @UlrichVonRekkenin What are you trying to tell with? Template parameters are the same because they need to be, how else could you have a generic reference to an array? The pattern yet occurs at many other locations, too - have you looked at the std::begin/end variants for arrays, for example?

Answer (score 1):

As stated already the problem here is that arrays decay to pointers when passed to a function, meaning that the size is not preserved.

If however you *knew* that there were 16 elements in the array you could do this:

```
array<int,16> copyarray(const int input[]) {
    array<int, 16> result;
    copy_n(input, size(result), begin(result));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You can preserve size using `template<unsigned N> array<int,N> copyarray(const int (&input)[N]) { ... }` if you aren't attached to 16. Edit -- Aconcagua parametrized this way but with `class T` instead of `int` as well.

Comment: @JohnP Yup, just presenting this as an alternative.