# How to convert int[4] to std::array<int,4>?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

I have a language built-in array and I need to copy its elements to the container library array for some processing. I have tried couple of things but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to convert one type to another?

A language built-in array is declared as:

```
int arr[] = {1,12,343,54,99};
```

While the library container array is declared as:

```
std::array<int,4> myarray = {4, 26, 80, 14} ;
```

std::array is declared under header `<array>`.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Do you want to copy the values from a `int[]` to a `std::array<int>`? In your example are `arr` and `myarray` related in any way?

Comment: I think this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219721/assign-c-array-to-cs-stdarray-stdarrayt-u-tu-no-suitable-const) answers your question.

Comment: @CoryKramer Sorry, I made is more clear. Please check.

Comment: I’ve never heard the term “container library array” in the context of C++. Just say `std::array`. Same, to some extent, for “built-in array” vs the more common “C-style array”.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I got this term from here(http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/), scroll down till last. Thanks.

Comment: @DominikJastrzębski Yes. That exactly what I wanted. I shall write an answer myself after understanding the linked post. Thanks.

Comment: @PankajMishra Ah. cplusplus.com is a bit rubbish unfortunately. Googling for the term shows that they basically invented the term, it’s not used anywhere else.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Then the domain name is pretty delusional. It seems the most genuine one.

Comment: @PankajMishra It’s definitely *not* the most “genuine” one. Anybody can register domain names, and cplusplus.com simply happened to be the first to grab it. They are in no way authoritative, and most experts tend to avoid the site. The “official” website is https://isocpp.org/, and a pretty good reference is https://cppreference.com/.

Comment: cppreference.com is broadly considered the "official unofficial reference" for C++.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks. This is a new info for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For C++20, this is what `std::to_array` is for.

```cpp
int arr[] = {1,12,343,54};
std::array<int,4> myarray = std::to_array(arr); // could use "auto myarray" instead
```

Prior to C++20, you'd use `std::copy`, or `std::move` if your element type is noncopyable or costly to copy:

```cpp
int arr[] = {1,12,343,54};
std::array<int, 4> myarray;
std::copy(arr, arr+4, myarray.begin());
// or
std::copy(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), myarray.begin());
```

Comment: This does answer my question. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the implementation of `to_array` uses anything C++20 specific, so @PankajMishra can just copy the implementation from [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/to_array). Also note, that while `std::copy` is perfectly fine for `int` there are types for which you probably would want to use [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) (not the cast, but the algorithm).

Comment: Yay for c++ 20!