# Cast an unstructured array as structured (with structure of a not compile-time known size)

Tags: c++, casting

I have a raw array from a low-level library `double[] a` of known size.

This array is in fact filled with subarrays of same size, i.e. `a == [p0[n], p1[n], ... pM[n]]`. 
I need to shuffle the subarrays, i.e. to make a permutation of `p0[n], ..., pM[n]`. For this I can use `std::random_shuffle`, but I have to cast the raw array to an array, where each element has `sizeof(p) == n * sizeof(double)`. The `n` is defined by a variable and not compile-time known.

How would I do that or is it possible at all?

Comment: You need to convert every C-subarray to std::array, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26219721/3871028)

Comment: @Ripi2 thanks for the reply, but I decided to write a simple Fisher–Yates shuffle with `std::swap_ranges` on the raw array, which is easier than implementing my own random access iterator