# Why to use _tcscpy_s instead of _tcscpy?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I am new to C++ programming. I am carrying out an SAST violations check for my code, and the scan throws a warning:

```
_tcscpy(destination_array,Source);
```

> The dangerous function, _tcscpy, was found in use at line 58 in Source.cpp file. Such functions may expose information and allow an attacker to get full control over the host machine

So instead, now I had to use this which makes the warning go away:

```
_tcscpy_s(destination_array,_countof(destination_array),Source);
```

What is the actual difference between `_tcscpy` and `_tcscpy_s`, and how does it make the code safe?

Comment: It's all documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-s-wcscpy-s-mbscpy-s and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/security-features-in-the-crt?view=msvc-160

Comment: Don't forget to look at std::copy. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy
it is safe, and it can even outperform other copy functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707012/is-it-better-to-use-stdmemcpy-or-stdcopy-in-terms-to-performance)

Comment: Why are you considering using either? Even if there is a good reason to be working with C strings rather than using the classes from the C++ std lib, why would you be using generic text functions? Surely you aren't trying to support Windows 9x and Windows NT with the same codebase. Surely your code can settle on using the native UTF-16 encoding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual difference is that `_s` functions check the destination buffer before writing to it. If the buffer is too small then either the program is aborted, or an error value is reported, depending on the current error handler.

This prevents buffer overrun attacks, when malicious data is formed in some specific way to overwrite other data and gain the control over the program.

Sure the prevention only works if the size of destination buffer is passed correctly. If not, buffer overruns and attacks are still possible.

Even if the application does not have security implication, it may be useful to use `_s` functions anyway to avoid hard to pinpoint memory corruption bugs.

Visual C++ provides a templated version of `_tcscpy_s`, so for arrays instead of

```c
_tcscpy_s(destination_array,_countof(destination_array),Source);
```

you can use

```c
_tcscpy_s(destination_array,Source);
```

this is even more safe, as the size is deduced, so an incorrect size is not possible.