# Is there a function for moving the contents of a char array a certain amount of addresses back in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I have the following code for Arduino (C++). This is for a checksum consisting of 2 characters forming a base 16 value between 0 and 255. It takes int outputCheckSum and converts it to char outputCheckSumHex[3].

```
itoa (outputCheckSum, outputCheckSumHex, 16)
  if (outputCheckSum < 16) { //Adds a 0 if CS has fewer than 2 numbers
    outputCheckSumHex[1] = outputCheckSumHex[0];  
    outputCheckSumHex[0] = '0';
  }
```

Since the output of itoa would be "X" instead of "0X" in the event of X having fewer than 2 characters, the last 3 lines are to move the characters one step back.

I now have plans to scale this up to a CS of 8 characters, and I was wondering whether there exists a function in C++ that can achieve that before I start writing more code. Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: There is `std::copy_backward`. But this looks like a forward move, not a backward one. So, just `std::copy`.

Comment: Use std::copy, it will copy memory from one location to another.

Comment: `outputCheckSumHex[0] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[outputCheckSum >> 8]; outputCheckSumHex[1] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[outputCheckSum & 0xFF];`?

Comment: BTW: There are arduino c++ compilers without the std:: namespace. By default they complain about `'copy' is not a member of 'std'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `memmove`, it's one of the legacy C functions rather than C++ but it's available in the latter (in `cstring` header) and handles overlapping memory correctly, unlike `memcpy`.

So, for example, you could use:

```c
char buff[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '.', '.'};
memmove(&(buff[2]), &(buff[0], 3);
// Now it's {'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c'} and you can replace the first two characters.
```

Alternatively, you could use `std::copy` from the `algorithm` header but, for something this basic, `memmove` should be fine.

Comment: C++ has std::copy which will have an optimized implementation and is more typesafe

Comment: @PepijnKramer, you should be wary of blanket statements like "will have an optimised implementation", it's by no means guaranteed. In any case, `memmove()` is probably also likely to be optimised and is perfectly adequate for character handling such as requested here.

Comment: @PepijnKramer There's exactly zero difference between type safeness between the two when copying char arrays - which is what OP asked for. Granted, we wouldn't move smart pointers and lock around like this - but that's not what OP asked for. Specific question, specific answer.

Comment: Related: [Is it better to use std::memcpy() or std::copy() in terms to performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4707012/3212865) (despite the name answers go beyond pure performance aspect). The TLDR: there is absolutely no reason to use `memcpy` / `memmove` except old habits.

Comment: @paxdiablo It is not a blanket statment. std::copy has a performance benefit (vectorizing compilers). Try it in compiler explorer :)

Comment: @PepijnKramer: if you'd like to point out the part of ISO C++ that states it *must* be vectorised, I'd be happy to concur. I couldn't find it myself :-) It has mandated performance characteristics like "exactly N assignments" but any _decent_ `memmove` would also have that characteristic. And, in fact, it could use fewer assignments in the byte case since it could choose to assign multiple bytes at once. Now `std::copy` _may_ also be able to do that but I think it would probably require a specialised template and I'm not convinced that wouldn't violate the "exactly N" mandate in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `memmove` in `<cstring>` for this. It does not check for terminating null characters, but instead copies `num` bytes (third argument) and works with overlapping regions as well.

```
void* memmove(void* destination, const void* source, size_t num);
```

Comment: No those functions have more of a place in "C" then "C++" just use std::copy. Anything with void* is a code smell (in C++).

Comment: @PepijnKramer We don't agree on this one. The fact that is takes `void*` is to be able to work with any POD type. It does exactly what OP requires and is part of the standard, so I don't understand the downvote, either.

Comment: Related: [Is it better to use std::memcpy() or std::copy() in terms to performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4707012/3212865) (despite the name answers go beyond pure performance aspect). The TLDR: there is absolutely no reason to use `memcpy` / `memmove` except old habits.

Comment: @lorro I can agree to disagree :) But for me the fact is that void* breaks typesafety. And in all my years of development I find that the typesafety is a very important feature of any development environment and specially C++. It allows the compiler to catch bugs before they happen. For example it is one of the reasons I always model options as enums and not as bools, they are semantically different and types allow you to model that semantic difference. (And yes I do go one step beyond asking OP question directly with that)