# Using memcpy with smart pointers in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a smart pointer defined like this

```
     auto ptr = make_shared<int[]>(5);
```

and another array

```
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

I want to copy data in arr to ptr, I tried using this

```
    memcpy(ptr.get(), arr, 5 * sizeof(int))
```

But when I try printing like this

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout<<ptr[i]<<std::endl;
    }
```

I get

```
malloc(): corrupted top size

Process finished with exit code 134
(interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

Is there something wrong with the ptr initialization ?

Comment: `memcpy(ptr.get(), arr, 5*sizeof(int));`

Comment: Because you're copying 5 bytes instead of 5 elements of type int.

Comment: @AlexF with this i get `malloc(): corrupted top size`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your malloc corruption. See [godbolt here](https://godbolt.org/z/4zh1s5K3P). Please post the entire code to reproduce this

Comment: [Not reproduced](https://godbolt.org/z/r38TEW51x)

Comment: @Homer512 what does this produce on your pc then `    auto ptr = make_shared<int[5]>();
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::memcpy(ptr.get(),arr,5*sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout<<ptr[i]<<std::endl;
    }`

Comment: `make_shared<int[5]>()`is not what you posted in your question.

Comment: I can reproduce it in GCC using onlinegdb. If I access any element of the shared pointer prior to memcpy, the issue goes away.

Comment: @Homer512 which is the correct way

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov I am using gcc yes

Comment: `make_shared` for array types is part of the experimental C++20 support in GCC-12. See [the release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-12/changes.html) It fails on GCC-11 and earlier in my tests

Comment: Have you looked at [std::copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)? It is the (typesafe) C++ equivalent of memcpy and it will [not be slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707012/is-it-better-to-use-stdmemcpy-or-stdcopy-in-terms-to-performance).

Comment: The workaround for missing `make_shared`support is `std::shared_ptr<int[]>(new int[5])`. Less efficient but compatible with C++17 and works with GCC-7 and up